# Авторизация с помощью Google не работает после публикации приложения в Google Play

Tags: java, android, firebase, аутентификация

Собрал приложение Android App Bundle (AAB), вариант "release", то есть это не "debug", после опубликовал в Google Play, скачав приложение я не могу авторизоваться с помощью Google, хотя когда я компилирую код из Android studio напрямую, то всё работает, подскажите в чем может быть проблема, и как её исправить.

Сначала я думал что при релизе, что-то происходит с токеном поэтому и возникает такая проблема, но нет, это тут не причём, потом я где-то вычитал что это из-за "gson", но я использую библиотеку от Google `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` и вроде этот вариант тоже отпал, потом я вспомнил, что у меня была похожая проблема с сменой языка, но после добавления в `build.gradle` данного кода:

```
bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
```

Всё пофиксилось само собой, может нужно где-то подобное для `firebase auth` добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% что проблема в ключе подписи. AAB формат подразумевает, что гугл удаляет вашу подпись и заменяет её своей. Отпечаток ключа подписи гугл в консоли магазина приложений вам показывает. Надо этот отпечаток из консоли магазина скопировать в консоль Firebase и/или GoogleCloudConsole в настройках логина (сейчас там, видимо, только отпечаток дебажного ключа (ну или дебажного плюс загрузочного (условно релизного))).

После этого, возможно, нужно ещё обновить конфиг Firebase в файлах проекта, пересобрать приложение и обновить в магазине.